# Visual studio C# Собранный проект не запускается на другом пк

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Собранный проект не запускается на другом пк. Вроде все нужные файлы находятся в папке Debug. Проект во вложении. Подскажите пожалуйста. Проект заливается на локальную диск C и от туда запускается. На моем пк работает запускается. Заливаем на другую пк ошибку не выдает просто молчание. Net Framework 4.8 установлены.
[Ссылка на проект](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/-V-2hGb2FFlkgw)

Comment: Журнал Windows смотрите, Win+R `compmgmt.msc` - Журналы - Приложение (Application), там искать ошибку в своём приложении. Framework 4.8 - устаревший дотнет, используйте .NET 6 или новее.

Comment: Тип приложения укажите в метках.

Comment: Уберите абсолютные пути из проекта или укажите, что файл надо запускать из C:\FireSecurity_wf\

Comment: @Виктор первая половина совета хорошая, вторая плохая, но для начала надо текст исключения из автора вытащить.

Comment: Надо отсюда скачать SQL Express 2019 - https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=866658

Comment: @aepot System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "The database 'C:\FIRESECURITY_WF\FIREDB.MDF' cannot be opened because it is version 904. This server supports version 852 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
Could not open new database 'C:\FIRESECURITY_WF\FIREDB.MDF'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\FireSecurity_wf\fireDB.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share."

Comment: @aepot У Автора там абсолютные пути к базе, к звуковым файлам, поэтому - запускать из C:\FireSecurity_wf

Comment: @Виктор я не у вас просил ошибку, ва у автора. Только с толку сбили, у автора может быть совсем другая причина падения.

Comment: Спасибо за советы @aepot Разобрался. Установил SqlServerLocalDB заработал. В чем разница exe файла находящийся в папке C:\FireSecurity_wf\obj\Debug и C:\FireSecurity_wf\bin\Debug???

exe в папке C:\FireSecurity_wf\bin\Debug не запускается по прежнему

Comment: Папку obj вообще нельзя трогать, там лежит промежуточный вариант сборки. Debug сборку следует использовать только для отладки. Для публикации использовать следует Release сборку из папки bin. Я вам сказал, как посмотреть исключение, которое возникает и узнать, почему не запускается. Кстати, когда пересылаете проект в архиве, удаляйте папки bin и obj, у меня антивирус уничтожил архив, потому что в нем находятся исполняемые файлы.